# Maven surfire html report not coming

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I was trying to produce html report for test case .

But html report is not coming .Please help me.`

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report-only</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I was also the try the reporting and have same issue .I able to produce txt and xml files.

```
 <reporting>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>

  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: What is the maven command you invoke? The second option should be the correct one (in the reporting section). Invoke mvn clean test site to generate the report within the target/site subdirectory.

Comment: I have executed mvn clean install site.I have also tried mvn clean test site same issue.

Comment: Remove `<goal>report-only</goal>` and keep the `<reporting>` section. Run Maven with `mvn clean site` and you'll get a HTML report